# ssh: Could not resolve hostname server: Name or service not known

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to test my honeypot but for some reason I'm getting this message:

```
ssh root@server 10.0.2.15
ssh: Could not resolve hostname server: Name or service not known
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Add what command did you use for ssh.

Comment: the correct syntax for ssh would be this `ssh root@10.0.2.15`

Comment: @WooJoo Looks like you have the answer ;)

Comment: @WooJoo yes, that's the right answer , I can't believe I made such a simple mistake

Comment: @WooJoo Post the answer ;)

Comment: It is considered respectful to mark a solution once one is found for the benefit of others.

Comment: In my case the solution was to install avahi-daemon on server (LAN server) and (re)start server/service (what ever you like it).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To connect to an ssh server in a terminal you need:

1. The call `ssh` to start the program
2. The user name, which in your case is `root`
3. An `@` sign separating the user name from the server identification
4. The IP address or name of the server, which in your case is `10.0.2.15`

Assembled, the command looks like:

```
ssh root@10.0.2.15
```

in general terms, `ssh user@server`.

Alternatively, you can use the `-l` option to directly specify the login name and skip the `@` syntax:

```
ssh 10.0.2.15 -l root
```

Answer (score 19):

As WooJoo stated, you need to tell it a valid server to connect to. If you wanted to use the form `$ ssh root@server` you can, but you would need to have `server` as an entry in `/etc/hosts` or your dns server *(which is not the case or you would not have had an error)*, or an entry in a file called `config` located typically at `/home/username/.ssh/config`.

A sample /etc/hosts entry would look like:

```
# Sample /etc/hosts file
127.0.0.1    localhost
127.0.1.1    computerhostnamehere

10.0.2.15    server
```

and a sample /home/username/.ssh/config could be as simple as:

```
Host server
  HostName 10.0.2.15
  User root
```

This would get you the basic functionality you are looking for. There are many more options available for placing in the `~/.ssh/config` file.

See `man ssh` for more options :)

Answer (score 2):

Please try by adding  **server entry to which you are trying to ssh** in /etc/hosts file of machine from where you want to do ssh

Answer (score 2):

```
    ssh-copy-id user@host && chmod 0755 /root (if root user) or chmod 0755 /home/username
```

Comment: This probably won't solve the problem because of DNS resolution failing.